# Reading an ASP.NET session variable is super slow (30 seconds)!

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, session-variables

Debugging an operation that's performing slowly, I've discovered (to my astonishment) that the line:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentCompany"] == null)
```

takes about *30 seconds* to execute.

What could possibly be happening!? Anyone seen anything like this before?

(It's in a loadbalanced config with StateServer storing session, could that be related?)

Comment: Are all calls to Session[string] slow, or only the first call for each request?

Comment: Is it 'exactly' 30 seconds? I'm just thinking that the default connection timeout is 30 seconds on SQL, so perhaps it's a connection failure to the state server. Does the statement evaluate to true eventually?

Comment: Just to get this out of the way: Are you 100% sure it's that code? Have you tried using test constant values instead to make sure?

Comment: take one server offline; set session to inproc; test the app on just that server - to isolate the problem of the app having connectivity issues with the sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround: I changed the session provider in the web.config:

from "StateServer" to "InProc":

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
```

... and the pause went away.

(Most likely it had trouble reaching the stateserver, the current server is not where it was originally running from).

Thanks to all your suggestions, especially @Hari and @dougajmcdonald.

.

**Hindsight edit**
This may help someone later: The root cause of this issue seems to have been a method that made a huge number of very heavy SQL queries that occurred around the same time as this stateserver problem. I think these are related, not exactly sure how. I've had similar problems since, so if you have a session issue like this, look for heavy DB activity.